# How do you say "thud"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you say *thud* in Esperanto, as in *something heavy hitting the ground*? Are there multiple ways to say it?

Answer (score 8):

According to [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopeoj_en_Esperanto), the sound of falling objects is *Puf!* or *Pum!*, while *Bum!* is used for a "sudden, unexpected fall". See the PIV's definitions of *[Puf](http://vortaro.net/#puf)*, *[Pum](http://vortaro.net/#pum)*, and *[Bum](http://vortaro.net/#bum)*.